# Validação de login local

Tags: php, html

Preciso fazer uma validação de login sem banco de dados, ou seja, com as prórpias arrays que eu passar, mas não sei como verificar se existe um item dentro de uma array.

OBS: já tentei usar o `in_array`.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    //Pegando usuário e senha do formulário (index.php)
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    //Usúarios e senhas que podem ter acesso
    $users = array('admin', 'admin2', 'admin3', 'admin4', 'admin5');
    $senhas = array('senha', 'senha2', 'senha3', 'senha4', 'senha5');

    //Convertendo usuário e senha recebidos em apenas uma array
    $login = array($user, $pass);

    if (!empty($user) and !empty($pass)) {
        
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos.'); window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O PHP tem a função `array_search` que pode ser usada para o seu caso [confere na documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php) e se atente com o retorno dela.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'senha';

//Usúarios e senhas que podem ter acesso
$users = array('admin', 'admin2', 'admin3', 'admin4', 'admin5');
$senhas = array('senha', 'senha2', 'senha3', 'senha4', 'senha5');

$index = array_search($user, $users);

if ($index !== false && isset($senhas[$index]) && $senhas[$index] === $pass) {
    echo 'Login valido!';
}
else {
    echo 'Login incorreto!';
}
```